# Is it legal to put more than one input in a label element?

Tags: html, input, label

One use case is when I want to provide more than one method of setting the same value, for example:

```js
const inp1 = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0]
const inp2 = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[1]

inp1.oninput = ()=>{inp2.value = inp1.value}
inp2.oninput = ()=>{inp1.value = inp2.value}

inp1.value = 0
```

```html
<label>Set turn angle:
  <input type="number" min="-90" max="90" step="any">
  <input type="range" min="-90" max="90" step="any">
</label>
```

When the user wishes to enter a precise value they have the `number` input. Otherwise, if they wish to simply turn around a bit or keep turning slowly without having to type rapidly, they have the slider.

But! What about the `label` element? Semantically, the `label` applies to both inputs. However, is it allowed to put more than one input element in a label, as I did? I'm reading the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) and it seems to assume a 1-1 relation between a label and a corresponding input. Then, if it is not legal, what am I supposed to do in such a case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not valid to have multiple controls in a single label element. The content model for label says:

> Phrasing content, but with no descendant labelable elements unless it is **the element’s labeled control**, and no descendant label elements.

The element’s labeled control is clearly singular.

The labels are primarily for the benefit of screen readers, so that when the control receives focus via a TAB key, the label gets read out and the user understands what value they are setting. For example, testing in NVDA in Firefox, this works pretty well:

```js
const inp1 = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0]
const inp2 = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[1]

inp1.oninput = ()=>{inp2.value = inp1.value}
inp2.oninput = ()=>{inp1.value = inp2.value}

inp1.value = 0
```

```html
<fieldset>
<legend>Set turn angle:</legend>
<label for="n1">by number:</label>
<input type="number" min="-90" max="90" step="any" id="n1">
<label for="r1">by range:</label>
<input type="range" min="-90" max="90" step="any" id="r1">
</fieldset>
```

However when controlling via a keyboard, there's little value in having two controls. The range control provides no additional functionality. So another approach would be to hide the range control from being focussed by the TAB key.

```js
const inp1 = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0]
const inp2 = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[1]

inp1.oninput = ()=>{inp2.value = inp1.value}
inp2.oninput = ()=>{inp1.value = inp2.value}

inp1.value = 0
```

```html
<label for="n1">Set turn angle:</label>
<input type="number" min="-90" max="90" step="any" id="n1">
<input type="range" min="-90" max="90" step="any" tabindex="-1">
```